# Ruby + Compass: Permission Issues

Tags: ruby, git, sass, compass-sass

I have been having all sorts of permission issues using SCSS + Compass after pulling a GIT repo project that contains this. But works great if I created my own SASS project from scratch.

Inside my git repo project, where sass lies, I run:

```
compass watch
```

...and get...

```
>>> Change detected to: print.scss
Errno::EACCES on line 25 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb: Permission denied - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dt/resources/slice/html/.sass-cache/f2469bce8a00b9f9dd394c466620079eaa696535/print.scssc
```

So I logged in as root user and ran...

```
chmod 777 /Library/Ruby
```

...with no luck.

When I first installed Ruby, I used `sudo install gem ***`. Which everyone seems to use but then I read it a bad idea. (such as my case)

Tried installing a fresh copy of ruby while logged in as my normal admin user and don't have permissions to install it.

```
Fetching: compass-0.12.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

Which is why I went with the sudo route. So.
Bit stumped on why and how to fix this issue. Besides running everything off root user.

Forgot to add if this helps: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're having:

```
Errno::EACCES on line 25 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb: Permission denied - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dt/resources/slice/html/.sass-cache/f2469bce8a00b9f9dd394c466620079eaa696535/print.scssc
```

indicates not that you're having a permissions problem in /Library/Ruby, but that you're having a permissions problem in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dt/resources/slice/html/.sass-cache/f2469bce8a00b9f9dd394c466620079eaa696535/.  Correct the permissions in that directory and that problem should go away.

As to why you're having installation issues, that's a completely separate problem that I've got no idea about!

Comment: Totally works. Though the same problem continues whenever I pull a new git repo. As a quick solution I discovered that manually deleting the .sass-cache fixes those permission errors easily enough. Suppose it makes sense since these permissions from the cached sass files are being created on someone else's machine.